# Holonomy of hypercomplex manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, holonomy, quaternionic-geometry

The following is a quote from M. Barberis, I. Dotti, M. Verbitsky, *Canonical Boundles of Complex Nilmanifolds with Applications to Hypercomplex Geometry*, Math. Res. Lett., **16(2)**, 331-347, 2009.

"Not much is known about
$SL
(
n,
\mathbb{H}
)$-manifolds. It is easy to see that $(
M,
I
)$
has holomorphically trivial canonical bundle, when $(
M,
I
,
J
,
K
)$ is a hypercomplex manifold with holonomy in
$SL
(
n,
\mathbb{H}
)$ ([V2]). For a hypercomplex
$SL
(
n,
\mathbb{H}
)$-
manifold admitting a special kind of quaternionic Hermitian metric called
HKT
metric, a version of Hodge theory was constructed ([V1]). Using this result, it
was shown that a compact hypercomplex manifold with trivial canonical bundle
has holonomy in
$SL
(
n,
\mathbb{H}
)$, if it admits an HKT-structure ([V2]).

It is not clear whether the last condition is necessary: for all known
examples of hypercomplex manifolds with trivial canonical bundle, holonomy lies in
$SL
(
n,
\mathbb{H}
)$."

I don't understand what they mean in the last sentence. Clearly existence of HKT metric is not necessary for holonomy being in $SL
(
n,
\mathbb{H}
)$ since the example of Fino and Grantcharov is hypercomplex nilmanifold and as such has holonomy in $SL
(
n,
\mathbb{H}
)$ but it does not support HKT metric. Am I missing something?

Another (related) question is whether someone knows what is the current status of showing equivalence between holonomy in $SL
(
n,
\mathbb{H}
)$ and having trivial canonical bundle?

Comment: I think that, in that 'last' sentence, the authors probably meant "It is not clear whether the last condition [i.e., admitting an HKT-structure] is *needed for the conclusion*: for all known..."  What they were alluding to was the question of whether, in fact, *every* [compact] hypercomplex manifold with trivial $I$-canonical bundle (say) has holonomy in $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{H})$.  (Note that they clearly should have had the word 'compact' in the last phrase, since there are noncompact hypercomplex manifolds with trivial $I$-canonical bundle that have holonomy $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{H})$.)

Comment: @RobertBryant, aaa, You are probably right! Do You know perhaps what is the status of that equation?